# A sentence with all numbers

Tags: wordplay, lateral-thinking, open-ended

Crazy thought.

> Can you make an (grammatically correct) english sentence using english words which are all
>   numbers? Each word in that sentence must represent a number. I am
>   expecting a minimum 6 word sentence.

For example:

Answer to a question: How many Xs you see on that board?

**I see one X**

1 100 1   10

I= 1 in Roman Numeral

see = C (Lateral Thinking) = 100

One = 1

X = 10

Each word fully (no splitting) must be a number. A plural, if you use it, must be a number.

This is a bit open ended question but it was hard for me to construct > 6 word sentence.

Comment: What exactly counts as an English word? What counts as representing a number? The validity of an answer seems to depend on your opinions here.

Comment: How lateral is lateral? The example uses "see" which is not a number. So is "for" allowed because it sounds like **four**? Or "triad" because it represents **three**?

Comment: So I want to define Engish word as one in a Merriam Webster Dictionary. Since this is lateral thinking, for as 4 is fine but triad for 3 is a bit of a stretch.

Comment: "for as 4 is fine but triad for 3 is a bit of a stretch"? I would say the opposite. This sounds *exactly* like a question that fits the 'speculative answer' close reason: "The validity of some answers may be based upon opinion."

Comment: Defining a set of words that count, and then redefining the puzzle to be "make the longest grammatically correct English sentence using only these words" is IMO the only way to make this not 'speculative'/'bad subjective'.

Answer (score 1):

I am a visionary.

> I am one to foresee for one.
> (I M  1  2   4 C     4   1.)

Score: 7 words (8 numbers)

Inspired by

> [*Ralph 124C 41+,* by Hugo Gernsback.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ralph_124C_41%2B)